# What's the smartest way to solve this issue brute-force like?

Tags: java, algorithm, brute-force

I want to System.out.println/writeToFile every possible int that has 25 numbers which are either 0 or 1 (1101110001000001000111011, 1010111111110111111110101, ...).

This should be 2^25 (33554432) different ints.

Now my question: What is the smartest way to do this in Java?

Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: I would love if you could give me code for this.

Comment: It is brute-force. It can't be smart.

Comment: That may be, but there are smart brute-force solutions and not so smart brute-force solutions.

Comment: Recurse. You can thread it too.

Comment: If you have to print "every possible int" then there isn't a smart way, just use a for loop from 0 to 33554432...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a for loop for running from 0 to 2^25.
- Use [`Integer.tSotring( i, radix )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) or [`Integer.toBinaryString(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) to convert to a binary representation.
- Add padding zeros to fill those numbers, that do not have 25 (binary) digits.
- Write to file or console.

<sup>The term "brute force" implies, that the solution is not that smart, else you wouldn't have to use brute force ...</sup>

Comment: Use `Integer.toBinaryString(i)` instead. Its a bit faster.

Comment: How does this address the question ? He asked to print
"every possible int that has exactly 25 **equal** binary digits"

Comment: How does a loop from 0 to 2^25 ensure 25 equal digits of 1s or 0s? I do not see it.

Comment: @Harmlezz You edited the equal number of digits in there. There was no such mentioning in the original question. And with an odd number of digits you can't have an equal number of two digits ...

Comment: @AldurDisciple & Harmlezz I think you did not understand the question, but you are right, he said "25 equal digits" but thats not what he mean. The example output have not 25 equal digits and he said 33554432 different ints.

Comment: @AldurDisciple The Harmlezz edited to question to a different form.

Comment: So, um, I'm not a native english speaker, I hope one does understand my question.

Comment: @user3083408 Equal number of digits would mean something like `1100`, but you can't have that with with an odd number of total digits.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's not what I wanted. Now I will try your solution Sirko.

Comment: @Sirko Nah, that's not working. Since these various numbers also start with 0 (e.g. 0010101101010011011010011) you can't store it in an int.

Comment: @user3083408 You would not store them in an `int`, but in a `String` as the `to[Binary]String()` method suggests.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I had to add the missing zeros on the left side? I mean, if I get 1000 I had to add these zeros (here: x) like this: x1000?

Comment: @user3083408 That's what I meant with "padding zeros" just fill up until you've got the number of digits you wanted.